# Positioning h2 container inside parent container

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS so excuse my ignorance. I'm having trouble getting my h2 tag to cooperate within its container. I want h2 to be left justified within the surrounding container but I cant find the right function to do so.
my code is as below:

```
#about
    {
    width: 55%;
    font-size: 120%;
    }

h2
    {
    width: 130px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none; 
    border-left: none;
    border-width: 1px;  
    margin-top:7%;
    }
```

h2 is the text "About" and #about is the body of text below also housing h2.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Any suggestions?

As requested: http://jsfiddle.net/N786d/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but take a look at outline (css). That might solve your issue.

Comment: If you created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that would be helpful to us.

Comment: Text-align:left might be what you are looking for?

Comment: @ruddy http://jsfiddle.net/N786d/

Comment: @Edward it's not quite clear what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option given by CodingAnt will work, but it'll result in the white border on the right moving more to the right.
Just setting the margin-left to zero should work to.

```
h2 
    {
    margin-left: 0;
    }
```

Comment: I've edited the image to help better describe my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

You should increase the specificity of your CSS selector, to match only the `h2` of your navigation bar:

```
#nav h2{
    //Your actual rules
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N786d/15/)

---

If I understand you well, you should use the `[text-align][2]` property, which can have these values :

> text-align: start | end | left | right | center | justify | match-parent | start end

In your case, use the `left` value, and you should have the expected result!

Comment: Text-align is no use because I have left justify the h2 container inside the about container and not the text inside the h2 container.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **width to 100%** and set **text-align left** ,

```
text-align: left;    /*set text-align to left*/
width: 100%;        /*width change it to 100%*/
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/N786d/11/)</kbd>

Comment: If i set width to 100% than my right border is pushed 100% to the right.

Comment: I want the right border to be as its current distance from the text (as shown in the image). I just want to move that whole container (text and border) to the left of the parent container as oppose to its current center position.

Comment: Than use h2 
    {
    margin-left: 0;
    } as suggested by user @Arperum in his answer

Comment: Ah width was still set to 100% so margin-left:0 was doing nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to use `text-align:left`, but this affects only inline content, so you have also to set `display:inline-block` for the `h2` (which has `display:block` by default):

```
#about {
    ...
    text-align:left;
}

h2 {
   ...
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N786d/14/)